# Azure BlobServiceClient gives import error (occasionally)

Tags: python, azure, python-import

I get an **ImportError** with

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
```

I realised however that the error occurs when I install the dependencies as

```
pip install azure-storage-blob
pip install azure-storage
```

but not when I install them like

```
pip install azure-storage
pip install azure-storage-blob
```

The `pip freeze` shows the same libraries in both cases which are

```
azure-common==1.1.23
azure-core==1.0.0
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-storage==0.36.0
azure-storage-blob==12.0.0
certifi==2019.9.11
cffi==1.13.2
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.8
idna==2.8
isodate==0.6.0
msrest==0.6.10
oauthlib==3.1.0
pycparser==2.19
python-dateutil==2.8.1
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.13.0
urllib3==1.25.7
```

The second method works, however I am worried it will throw an error later on.
Is there a problem in the Azure library or am I missing something here?

Comment: If you’re working with just Azure Blob Storage, just use azure-storage-blob and not both.

Comment: Which version of Python ?

Comment: @RMPR Python 3.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GauravMantri said, you just install [`azure-storage-blob`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/) package if you want to use `from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient`, because the package `azure-storage-blob` is different with [`azure-storage`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage/), but they use the same namespace as the prefix.

So different installation order will get different result. For example, as below.

```
pip install azure-storage-blob
pip install azure-storage
```

The rear package `azure-storage` installation will cover the sample namespace `azure.storage.blob`, but not includes the class `BlobServiceClient`, just only the class `BlockBlobService` of `azure-storage`.

As reference, the `README.md` of GitHub repo [`Azure/azure-storage-python/tree/master/azure-storage-blob`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/tree/master/azure-storage-blob) also notice as the figure below, you must have to uninstall `azure-storage<=0.36.0` first when you want to use `azure-storage-blob`.

[image]

So if you use the incorrent installation order for these packages as my example, you must have to uninstall `azure-storage` first and install `azure-storage-blob`
again to avoid the potential error later.

Comment: Now I understand. My error was in thinking that `azure-storage-blob` and `azure-storage` were part of the same library. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please uninstall `azure-storage-blob` and `azure-storage`.

Then use this command:

```
pip install azure-storage-blob==12.0.0
```

The `BlobServiceClient` is in the [latest version 12.0.0 of azure-storage-blob](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0/)

Answer (score 0):

The package azure-storage is deprecated.

Please use these packages

https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/

https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-queue/

https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-share/

`pip install azure-storage-blob` would suffice, there is no need to install `azure-storage`.

Similarly, install queues and files if you are working on them.
Let me know if you still face the problem (  i work for the azure sdk team )